# SQL Query to find name ending with \\FileName

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there a way to find all records in a table that end with double slash e.g. `\\Test Sample.pdf`

```
DocPath ->
\\Main Documents\ROR456\ABC-1C9MUWP00B0-0022\\Test Sample.pdf
```

I tried this but no result:

```
SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE DocPath LIKE '[\\*.]$'
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the SPLIT_STRING function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions.   Try LIKE '%\\%' .

Comment: Your first sentence doesn't make sense.  First records don't "end" they have columns.  And the double slash is at the beginning -- not end -- of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
select right(DocPath, charindex('\\', reverse(DocPath)) + 1)
```

The above extracts the part after the last double backslash, which appears to be what you want.

However, a more literal interpretation of your query suggests you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM Reports
WHERE DocPath LIKE '%\\Test Sample.pdf'
```

Comment: Where is the table name in the query ?? Can you write complete query ?

Answer (score 0):

String manipulation is not a strong point of T-SQL, so the code that will do what is required will work slow and look ugly. Nevertheless, something like that might do the trick:

```sql
select t.Id, t.DocPath, ss.value
from (values
    (1, '\\Main Documents\ROR456\ABC-1C9MUWP00B0-0022\\Test Sample.pdf'),
    (2, '\\Main Documents\ROR456\ABC-1C9MUWP00B0-0022\Test Sample.pdf'),
    (3, '\Main Documents\ROR456\ABC-1C9MUWP00B0-0022\Test Sample.pdf'),
    (4, '\Main Documents\\ROR456\ABC-1C9MUWP00B0-0022\Test Sample.pdf')
) t (Id, DocPath)
    cross apply string_split(replace(t.DocPath, '\\', '['), '[') ss
where ss.value not like '%\%'
    and ss.value > ''
    and ss.value like '%.%';
```

If I would need to process a significant amount of records, I would consider an alternative. Off the top of the head:

- If it's some sort of ETL process, I would utilise .NET regexps in a SSIS dataflow component (source, or transformation), which would do the job in a much more elegant manner;
- For any kind of OLTP BAU activity that has to happen inside the database, I would probably resort to a CLR function, which would give the same C# / VB.Net capability as above.

P.S. Keep in mind that the `string_split()` function requires at least SQL Server 2016 and database compatibility level 130.